# увеличение ширины при наведении влево

Tags: html, css

Как заставить input увеличивать ширину при наведении влево? Сейчас когда наводишь на него ширина увеличавается в обе стороны(да, ширина input`a должна быть больше контейнера).
[Вот](https://jsfiddle.net/rsuwwdcu/) пример:
HTML:

```
 <div>
      <input id="search" type="search">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
  div {
      width: 150px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 2px solid black;
      text-align: right;
    }

    #search { 
    font-size: 12px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    width: 10px; 
    text-indent: 100%; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-position: center center;
    transition: width ease-in-out .15s;
    } 

    #search:hover,#search:focus { 
    cursor: text; 
    width: 200px; 
    background-position: right 10px center; 
    text-indent: 0; 
    white-space: normal; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сделали почти все правильно :)
Вам лишь надо было не давать таких подробных CSS инструкций на `transition`.

Тогда и абсолютного позиционирования не надо.

Чтобы раздвинуть input левее, надо лишь указать его длину побольше (что Вы сделали) + дать `margin-left: -50px;`.
Теперь транзакция между ними: вы указали `width` как параметр, но тогда проблема с `margin` - он не меняется. А если указать лишь `transition-duration`, то браузер сам все пересчитает.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: right;
}
#search {
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10px;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: center center;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}
#search:hover,
#search:focus {
  cursor: text;
  width: 200px;
  background-position: right 10px center;
  text-indent: 0;
  white-space: normal;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="search" type="search">
</div>
```

Учтите только, что вам может понадобиться добавить `webkit` CSS для кроссбраузерности

Comment: помогло спасибо, еще мини вопрос, если я не знаю точную ширину контейнера и он будет менять в зависимости от разрешения экрана, то как тогда быть?даже если указывать margin в % все равно в определенный момент поле начнет немного смещаться

Comment: Тогда указывайте и длину и `margin` в процентах. Т.е. например сейчас у Вас 100% = 150px (ширина исходного контейнера). Если при наведении поле должно быть 200% от своей начальной ширины, то в `:hover` пишите `width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;`.

Comment: спасибо,вы мне очень помогли

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}

#search { 
position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
font-size: 12px; 
cursor: pointer; 
width: 10px; 
text-indent: 100%; 
white-space: nowrap; 
overflow: hidden; 
background-position: center center;
transition: width ease-in-out .15s;
} 

#search:hover,#search:focus { 
cursor: text; 
width: 200px; 
background-position: right 10px center; 
text-indent: 0; 
white-space: normal; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="search" type="search">
</div>
```